# Linked Table Error: "Cannot find either column or the user-defined function or aggregate"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, view

This is the first time I've posted as I'm usually able to find my answers via previous posts, which is why I love StackOverFlow.

Anyway, I have two instances of SQL Server 2008 and want to link a table from `server1` to a view in `server2`. I've done this before without a problem, but I'm now getting the following error:

> Cannot find either column "DateOnly" or the user-defined function or
>   aggregate "DateOnly.ToString" or the name is ambiguous

when trying to execute the view. Please note, the view is very simple

```
Select * From Server1.catalog.dbo.table1
```

The column in question is a *date* datatype, not *datatime*, so I'm wondering if this is the reason and if so, why?

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: You don't *execute* a view - you select from it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier, If we could see whole definition of Your View. Maybe Your permission to "select" this column in table or view is denied ?